# Are there any downsides with having root access to mysql server by a normal user?

Tags: mysql

I have my Flask application configured to use the the root username and password to access the mysql server. If a normal user was to know these credentials, is there any probable disadvantage  that can be caused just my knowing the root password of mysql?

Answer (score 1):

You mean besides reading and writing all tables, creating new users, changing global variables, starting and stopping replication and shutting down the server? :-)

Also if they literally have access to the root MySQL user, instead of merely having SUPER privilege as a separate MySQL user, then this means you can't expire their access or revoke their privilege if you need to.

---

The MySQL root user is not the same as the Linux root user. Despite being the same name, MySQL root does not have access to the operating system. There are limited ways even the MySQL root user can use OS resources. For example, reading files with `LOAD DATA INFILE` or exporting data with `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`.

Unless you have extended the MySQL server with custom code in [server plugins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-plugins.html) or [server loadable functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-loadable-functions.html) that do OS-level operations in an unsafe way. But even then, the `mysqld` process typically runs as an operating system user "mysql" not the operating system user root.

Comment: Yeah besides from everything that can to done to the `mysql server` and its `content` itself, are there any other downsides. For example reading file root user, executing commands as root user or anything like that?